# Limit input field options JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, file-upload, user-input

I am working on a Wordpress website and I have a very simple `<input type="image">` through which user can send image files.

I have some very specific requests and I would like the uploaded file to be:

- min 3000x3000 px
- max 5000x5000 px
- max 36MB
- 1:1 aspect ratio

Is there a way I can set this limits via JS/jQuery?

Comment: Yes there is, but they are absolutely trivial for users to work around. If you add any validation to the client side it should be a courtesy to your users and to try and prevent wasted bandwidth. All business logic related, critical validation has to be done server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get info about image before upload use `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` . Aspect ratio is comparing width and height.

```
function test($file) {
    $data = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
    error_log(print_r($data,true));
    //Returns
    // Array (
    //     [0] => 3000 // width
    //     [1] => 3000 // height
    //     [2] => 3
    //     [3] => width="3000" height="30000"
    //     [bits] => 8
    //     [mime] => image/png
    // )
    error_log(print_r($file,true));
    //returns 
    // Array (
    //     [name] => filename.png
    //     [type] => image/png
    //     [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpEJC5NR
    //     [error] => 0
    //     [size] => 4347 // file size in bits
    // )
    return $file;
}
add_action('wp_handle_upload_prefilter','test');
```

Comment: This looks like it could be my solution. Would you mind giving me some explaination about this code? I'm not that good at this

Comment: wp_handle_upload_prefilter holds array of name - image name , type - file type , tmp_name is what wp generates before upload to check is it allowed image type for example or return error and we have size in bits which you can get in kb like $size = $file['size'] / 1024 . Since we know temp file address we can use the function getimagesize and get the rest of the information like width height mime type. There other functions for getting other stuff like shutter speed from camera if its recorded etc.  Check the codex for more info.

Comment: When you submit your image run the function. Then before return $file line do your magic to check your requirements. If meets your criteria return the file (upload it) or return error for example :)